# Running Code in VSCode Terminal Throws ModuleNotFound Error; But Running in Terminal on Mac Works Fine

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, openpyxl

Below is my code that I'm having the problem with. But when I run the script in the normal terminal on my machine it works fine. But when I run it in vscode I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'`.

```
import pandas as pd 

print("imported")
data = pd.read_excel("/Desktop/codes_sheet.xlsx")
print("data read")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['codes'])

print(df)
print(type(df))
```

Comment: You're probably running the code in VS Code with a different Python interpreter.  Simplest solution is to use virtual environments (which is a good idea anyway) and find the virtual environment in the list of available interpreters.

Comment: You can check which python version your package is installed in, and use `ctrl+shift+P` to switch python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks! now when I run it from my terminal too I get the same error even though pip list shows it installed. Any idea? Man this is frustrating

Answer (score 0):

`SHIFT-CMD+P` to get to the command panel and Select Interpreter to select the Python interpreter to use.

Ideally use a virtual environment

```py
python -m venv .venv
```

Creates a virtual environment called `.venv`

Then

```
. ./.venv/bin/activate
```

to activate it
and

```
pip install ...
```

To install you project packages

Then point to that environment in VS Code.

Refs:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html